# eXist-db cli automated workflow for adding a large number of zip files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, exist-db

I've got a local exist-db server running and I have over 1 million xml files I wish to add to it. The server is headless and I'm using the cli client. All of my files are in a collection of hundreds of zip files on the server, each with 5000-10000 files in them. My current workflow is manually adding each zip file using the client started in this manner:

```
eXist-db/bin/client.sh --no-gui
```

I'm using the `putzip` command and waiting for the indexing to complete and return me to the prompt:

```
exist:/db/collection> putzip /home/user/data/batch_01/xml_doc_01.zip

entering directory doc0001.xml
storing Zip-entry document doc0001.xml (1 of 5000) ...done

...

entering directory doc5000.xml
storing Zip-entry document doc5000.xml (5000 of 5000) ...done

parsed 1234567 bytes in 6000ms.

... *several minute delay*

exist:/db/collection>
```

I have several hundred zip files, so this would take a very long time to do manually. Is there an automated way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: I don't use (or even knew about) exist-db. But the manual suggest that it can be used in a **non-interactive mode**. Have you tried something like `eXist-db/bin/client.sh --no-gui putzip /home/user/data/batch_01/xml_doc_01.zip`?  Or, alternatively: `echo "putzip /home/user/data/batch_01/xml_doc_01.zip"|eXist-db/bin/client.sh --no-gui`? If either of these work you could just loop over your files; If the first one works it may even work with globbing, and you could possibly use `eXist-db/bin/client.sh --no-gui putzip /home/user/data/batch_01/xml_doc_*.zip` ...

Comment: @tink The echo suggestion does work. I will compose an answer based on your suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
find /path/to/base-directory -type f -name xml\*zip | while IFS= read -r name ; do
    echo "putzip ${name}" | eXist-db/bin/client.sh --no-gui
done
```

Should work - obviously untested.

Comment: I handled the scripting differently but this is the gist. I also need to add the -c option to start in the context of the collection I want to put the files into.

Comment: Pleased to hear that you have a working solution @Lokno